# Is there a drop-in replacement for YAML in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, yaml

I use hard tabs with my text editor, and I'm consistently being frustrated by YAML refusing to work with them. I'd rather choose a new language than change my habits.

So, is there some way to use, for example, JSON or XML for fixtures instead?
I'm still new to Rails, so I'm not sure if it allows for alternate syntax in fixtures.

Comment: For fixtures you can use brilliant https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_girl gem, but for configuration I am afraid you have to configure your editor for yml files to use spaces instead of tabs :( Next thing, Rails in default use coffee script instead pure JS... it will be the same problem for you.

Comment: Get a real editor, one that allows you to choose the correct style of indenting based on file type.

Comment: With internet standards you usually don't get a choice, so don't try to fight the flow. Use spaces. Besides, it'd standard in Ruby to use spaces, not tabs, for indenting because that maintains indenting correctly.

Comment: You used to be able to use csv for fixtures but that might have been retired.

Comment: I would advise on changing your habits instead. Using soft-tabs is a community wide convention. It's in all [style guides](https://github.com/bbatsov/ruby-style-guide#spaces-indentation) and pretty much all ruby and rails code is indented with two spaces. (Including rails source code itself.) And if you try to push tabs-intended code to some open-source projects I guarantee you'll annoy quite a few people.